# Unable to configure kubernetes URL with kubernetes-Jenkins plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes

Am new to kubernetes and trying out Jenkins kubernetes plugin. I have created a K8s cluster and namespace called jenkins-pl in AWS. Below are my Jenkins deployment and service yaml files:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: contactsai123/my-jenkins-image:1.0
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlp-port
              containerPort: 50000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

Here is my `jenkins-service.yaml` file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: jenkins
```

Am able to launch Jenkins successfully, am unsure on what should I provide in kubernetes URL.

I gave "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local" and get the error message:

```
Error testing connection https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1/namespaces/jenkins-pl/pods. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jenkins-pl:default" cannot list pods in the namespace "jenkins-pl".
```

I executed the command:

```
 $ kubectl cluster-info | grep master
```

and got the following output:

```
 https://api-selegrid-k8s-loca-m23tbb-1891259367.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I provided the above in Kubernetes URL, for which I get the similar error as before.

Not sure how to move forward?

Comment: When did you create the namespace `jenkins-pl`?

Answer (score 3):

Your cluster has RBAC enabled. You have to give your deployment necessary RBAC permission to list pods.

Consider your deployment as a user who need to perform some task in your cluster. So, you have to provide it necessary permission.

At first you have to create a role. It could be [ClusterRole or Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole).
This role define what can be done under this role. A ClusterRole give permission to do some task in cluster scope where Role give  permission only in a particular namespace.

Then, you have to create a [Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/). Consider service account as a user. It is for application instead of a person.

Finally, you have to bind Role or ClusterRole to the service account through [RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding). This actually tell that which user/service can access permissions defined under which roles.

Check this nice post to understand RBAC: [Configuring permissions in Kubernetes with RBAC](https://medium.com/containerum/configuring-permissions-in-kubernetes-with-rbac-a456a9717d5d)

Also this video might help you to understand the basics: [Role Based Access Control (RBAC) with Kubernetes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLktpM--0jA)